ADF Lookup Activity sometimes not returning value after changing to the new SnowflakeV2 linked service
I have the following lookup activity in ADF pipeline where it is using the new SnowflakeV2 linked service. However, sometimes it does not return any value even though the query is correct. I have never experience something like this before using the old Snowflake linked service.
Can someone help advise what is wrong and how to ensure that the value is return?
Attached below is the pipeline json:
{

    "name": "4_1 Curated to Transformed",
    
    "properties": {
    
        "activities": [
    
            {
    
                "name": "Lookup Job Details Transformed Table",
    
                "type": "Lookup",
    
                "dependsOn": [],
    
                "policy": {
    
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
    
                    "retry": 0,
    
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
    
                    "secureOutput": false,
    
                    "secureInput": false
    
                },
    
                "userProperties": [],
    
                "typeProperties": {
    
                    "source": {
    
                        "type": "SnowflakeV2Source",
    
                        "query": {
    
                            "value": "SELECT * FROM ETL_CONFIG.T_ETL_CONFIG_DETAILS_TRANSFORMED_MAIN WHERE ACTIVE_IND = 'TRUE' AND JOB_ID = '@{pipeline().parameters.jobID}' ORDER BY CONFIG_DETAIL_ID",
    
                            "type": "Expression"
    
                        },
    
                        "exportSettings": {
    
                            "type": "SnowflakeExportCopyCommand"
    
                        }
    
                    },
    
                    "dataset": {
    
                        "referenceName": "SF_ETL_CONFIG_new",
    
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
    
                        "parameters": {
    
                            "schemaName": "ETL_CONFIG",
    
                            "tableName": "T_ETL_JOB_DETAILS_MAIN"
    
                        }
    
                    },
    
                    "firstRowOnly": false
    
                }
    
            }
    
        ],
    
        "parameters": {
    
            "jobID": {
    
                "type": "string",
    
                "defaultValue": "4030"
    
            },
    
            "businessArea": {
    
                "type": "string"
    
            },
    
            "email": {
    
                "type": "string"
    
            },
    
            "Load_Group": {
    
                "type": "string"
    
            }
    
        },
    
        "folder": {
    
            "name": "Athena/4 Curated to Transformed"
    
        },
    
        "annotations": [],
    
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-11-24T06:20:51Z"
    
    },
    
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"

}

I have tried testing the query used on ADF directly on Snowflake and it works, not sure if it is ADF issue or Snowflake issue


First check the query where you are using the @{pipeline().parameters.jobID} expression for the JOB_ID value is passed correctly while executing the pipeline.
Check lookup input parameter is getting passed correctly.

If no row satisfies the query conditions (like ACTIVE_IND = 'TRUE' or matching JOB_ID), it will return no results. check if the query conditions in Snowflake always return data.

Check this document for mor about lookup with snowflake connector.

Hi Pratik, thanks for your response. I have tested the query in Snowflake and values are being returned. Using the same query, sometimes it return a value but sometimes it doesn't in ADF. Would like to check what is the cause of it and want to understand how to prevent it
